# How to arrange the list in my navbar horizontally?

Tags: html, css, list, navbar

I am fairly new to css and while working on a project I couldn't get the Inline-block code to work, and I cant understand why. I want to arrange the links in my navbar menu horizontally rather than vertically.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="max-width">
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">Roulathul <span>Uloom.</span></a></div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is my navbar HTML code.

```
.navbar .menu .li{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}
```

And this is where I used the inline block. Any Tips?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.menu {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: It worked but there's a tiny problem, now they are bunched together with no space between and bullets on the text. Tried using spaces in the name itself like <a>  home</a> but it doesn't work

Comment: Check this out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ In your case you have to use the `justify-content`. By default it is `flex-start` so you can play around with `space-between` or `space-around`

Comment: You can add a right margin for each list item (li).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I mainly center my navbars, just use the `display: flex` and `justify-content:` to either space out the elements or center them.
[More info on the flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
.menu{
list-style: none;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added padding for space and removed the default list styling, hope this helps:-

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0px;
}

.navbar ul {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">Roulathul <span>Uloom.</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li class="item"><a href="#Home">About</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#Clients">Skills</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#Contact Us">Teams</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#Contact Us">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```